# Extjs 5 grid binding after page change

Tags: extjs, pagination, grid, bind

I am using Extjs 5 to build a simple management system. One of our requirements is to bind an "audit" button to a grid's selection, if some attribute, like 'attrA', is true, then enable audit button, otherwise not. The problem i encountered was that once the page number was changed, the binding does not work. It seems that this problem was caused by **remote pagination**. Maybe i need to rebind the audit button with gird once the page number of gird was changed? Could you please help me with this, i am a newbie to extjs(work with it only one week). I am glad to hear a nice solution to fix the problem. Following is the key code section for you:

Grid definition:

```
.
.
itemId: 'orderGrid',
reference:'orderGrid',
xtype : 'grid',
.
.
```

Audit button definition:

```
{
 xtype : 'button',
 text : 'audit',
 glyph : 0xf044,
 handler : 'onModify',
 bind : {
    disabled : '{!orderGrid.selection.needAudit}'
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is extjs 5.1 bug as i previously reported here : http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?297085-grid-selectionchange-event-not-fires-when-using-paging

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to fix this problem? I mean the way using "override" function provided by extjs instead of modifying it's source code.

Comment: I couldn't find a good work around for this. I just listen to store's load event and inside it manage my problem.  ( for example by raising the select event again for the grid).also Extjs mentioned that corrected the problem but you should wait for the next GPA version!